# how to use Html.RenderPartial with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderpartial

i am trying to create user reviews under each product, i used `Html.RenderAction`

```
 Html.RenderAction("ProductReviewTest", new { id = productids });
```

it works fine but it takes 9.4s to load the product page with the reviews, so tried Html.RenderPartial but gives error

**my product view:**

```
@model MVCProduct.Models.Product

<!--here displaying products-->

<!--displaying reviews in same view-->

<div class="display-field">
<p> Reviews for @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductTitle) </p>
@{ 

int productid = Model.ProductID;

Html.RenderPartial("ProductReviewTest", new { id = productid });

}

</div>
```

**my review view model:**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ReviewTitle { get; set; }
    public string ReviewMessage { get; set; }
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ReviewStatus { get; set; }

}
```

**my ViewResult:**

```
 public PartialViewResult ProductReviewTest(int id)
    {

    List<ProductViewModel> productviewmodel = (from a in dbo.ProductReviews 
    where a.ProductID ==id
    select new ProductViewModel
        {
             ReviewId=a.ReviewId, 
             ProductID=a.ProductID,
             ReviewTitle =a.ReviewTitle,
             ReviewMessage =a.ReviewMessage,
             Rating =a.Rating,
             CustomerName =a.CustomerName,
             ReviewStatus=a.ReviewStatus
        }).ToList();



        return PartialView(productviewmodel);
    }
```

**my review view:**

```
   @model IEnumerable<MVCProduct.Models.ProductViewModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReviewId)
        </th>
.......

</table>
```

**error:**

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a 
>   model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Review.Models.ProductViewModel]'.

any help would be great.

Comment: you need to understand the difference between `RenderAction` and `RenderPartial`. In the first you are calling action, but in second, you are directly calling partial view. So you cannot pass `productId` in `RenderPartial`, instead you need to pass `List<ProductViewModel>`. Also in `RenderPartial`, you need to give partial view name, not action name.

Comment: @ramiramilu, thank you so much, i created a PartialView by right click add view, checked create partial view and now it works, ok which is fast Html.RenderPartial or Html.RenderAction ?

Comment: It depends, if you are using `RenderAction`, you are calling the same linq query again and again which is costly because of DB hits. But if you want to get all items at once and then use `RenderPartial` then you can avoid most of the DB hits.

Comment: Can I post the comment as answer?

Comment: yes sure , it will help someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `RenderAction` and `RenderPartial`. In the first you are calling action, but in second, you are directly calling partial view.

So you cannot pass `productId` in `RenderPartial`, instead you need to pass `List<ProductViewModel>`. Also in `RenderPartial`, you need to give partial view name, not the action name.

Comment: hi, one more query, does it make any difference using `PartialViewResult` with `return PartialView` and `ActionResult` with `return View` while using `Html.RenderPartial` ?

Comment: Typically there is no difference between `ViewResult` and `PartialViewResult`, both render response stream.

Answer (score 1):

**ViewResult:**

```
public PartialViewResult ProductReviewTest()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

**product view:**

```
@model MVCProduct.Models.Product

<!--here displaying products-->

<!--displaying reviews in same view-->

<div class="display-field">
<p> Reviews for @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductTitle) </p>
@{ 

int productid = Model.ProductID;

Html.RenderPartial("ProductReviewTest", Model.ProductReviews });

}

</div>
```

Comment: thank you @joaoeduardorf, but i guess you forget to mention to create partial views

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a List of ProductViewModel to view. 
Instead use

```
var productviewmodel = (from a in dbo.ProductReviews 
where a.ProductID ==id
select new ProductViewModel
    {
         ReviewId=a.ReviewId, 
         ProductID=a.ProductID,
         ReviewTitle =a.ReviewTitle,
         ReviewMessage =a.ReviewMessage,
         Rating =a.Rating,
         CustomerName =a.CustomerName,
         ReviewStatus=a.ReviewStatus
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

return PartialView(productviewmodel);